# Finding all similar lines in a text file

Tags: c#, string, file, file-io

I have a text file that contains some comma separated values. and it looks like this:

```
3,23500,R,5998,20.38,06/12/2013 01:44:17
2,23500,P,5983,20.234,06/12/2013 01:44:17
3,23501,R,5998,20.38,06/12/2013 01:44:18
2,23501,P,5983,20.235,06/12/2013 01:44:18
3,23502,R,6000,20.4,06/12/2013 01:44:19
2,23502,P,5983,20.236,06/12/2013 01:44:19
3,23503,R,5999,20.39,06/12/2013 01:44:20
2,23503,P,5983,20.236,06/12/2013 01:44:20
```

My task is to extract lines that start with same number in unique files. Eg in the above case you see some lines are starting with `2` and some with `3`...there can be more cases like `4` and etc...

What would be the best and fastes approach to do this? The files that I am working with are quite big and sometimes are in magnitude of gigabytes...

I did split each line and store the first value that will be the number I am looking for in an array and then remove duplicate values from the array...it works but it is very slow!

This is my own code:

```
private void buttonBeginProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);
    var nodeId = new List<int>();

    foreach (var line in file)
    {
        nodeId.Add(int.Parse(line.Split(',')[0]));
    }

    //Unique numbers
    nodeId = nodeId.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What is your expected output?

Comment: @SamLeach I explained what I have tried so far at the end of question.

Comment: Post the code so we can understand what you need.

Comment: Do you have to use C# for this, or is it a one-off task that you could do using other tools?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Well I am doing this in C# so thats the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(myFilePath);
var lineGroups = lines
                  .Where(line => line.Contains(","))
                  .Select(line => new{key = line.Split(',')[0], line})
                  .GroupBy(x => x.key);
foreach(var lineGroup in lineGroups)
{
    var key = lineGroup.Key;
    var keySpecificLines = lineGroup.Select(x => x.line);
    //save keySpecificLines to file
}
```

Comment: you could just just line[0] instead of splitting it

Comment: That assumes that the initial field is only 1char wide.

Comment: Given that the questioner specifically mentions CSV, it's probably best to respect that the C in CSV is a comma.

Comment: @Sayse: Ta. You'll be pleased to know that your vote pushed me over the 40k mark and now I can get back to work!

Comment: @Sayse No..wgat if the number is 2 or more digits?!

Comment: @spender Thanks for the answer...but I can't see much improvement over my own code :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` to process each file one line at a time:

```
var writers = new Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        var key = line.Split(new[]{ ',' },2)[0];
        if (!lineGroups.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            writers[key] = new StreamWriter(GetPathToOutput(key));
        }

        writers[key].WriteLine(line);
    }
}

foreach(StreamWriter sw in writers.Values)
{
    sw.Dispose();
}
```

With this method, you ensure that your code never has to consume the entire input file, so it shouldn't matter how large your input files are. Of course the downside is it would have to keep an arbitrary number of files open throughout the process.